# Sails.js + PageDown -- How to call the add-on

Tags: node.js, sails.js, pagedown

I want to add Pagedown (Stack Exchange's markdown, installed from npm) to Sailsjs.  I have it properly 'required' in my application.js file, however I am stumped as to how to use it anywhere outside of said file.

My goal is to use Pagedown either in a controller's action function, or for a model's beforeUpdate(). Any leads?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you add a service (./api/services/) with the name pagedown.js containing:

```
module.exports = require("pagedown");
```

you have the pagedown object globally available.

Comment: Could you cite any relevant documentation for similar questions in the future?